# Spring - jdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I'm just beginning with Spring framework. I'm also using DBCP pooling and i'm still not sure how to work right with jdbcTemplate.

It is best practice to reuse created/injected jdbcTemplate instance between multiple DAOs or it is right to create jdbcTemplate for each DAO ?

I'm currently using annotation approach:

```
public class FooDAO  {

  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Autowired
  public void setDatasource( DataSource dataSource ) {
     this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate( dataSource );
  }
}
```

I'm aware about JdbcDaoSupport, but I don't know how to inject datasource, because method setDatasource is marked as final.

But still, I'm not sure if is best practice to reuse created jdbcTemplate or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inject it in and share it.  Don't call "new"; that takes control out of the hands of the Spring bean factory.

Comment: In first and foremost, thank you for your reply, but i'm not sure if I understand your advice well. My DAOs are marked as @Service, so they are managed as bean by spring. My DAOs are injected into services. Reusing jdbcTemplate is good approach, that I understand. But I'm not sure if is there elegant way how to do it.

Maybe JdbcDaoSupport class should be that solution.

Comment: Sure.  The point is that you should have Spring give you that data source; don't call "new" and create it yourself.

Comment: Your thanks are welcome, but this site gives you the change to vote up and accept answers that help.  If you find that this fixes your problem, say so by voting up and accepting.

Comment: Well, now I'm not sure if I understand you well. DataSource is provided by Spring, i'm not creating the new one. In every DAO example is setter "setDatasource( DataSource dataSource)" with "this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate( dataSource )". But, if is jdbcTemplate sharing good, how to share this instance between DAO's. Because every DAO has setDataSource method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware about JdbcDaoSupport, but I don't know how to inject datasource, because method setDatasource is marked as final.

```
public class JdbcDaoSupportTest extends JdbcDaoSupport {

    public void insert() { 
        this.getJdbcTemplate().execute("insert into  tb_test1 values(1,'ycl','123')");
         System.out.println("complete...");
    }
}
```

Spring call set Method, don't care whether the method is final or not.

```
<bean id="jdbcDaoSupportTest" class="com.xxxxx.JdbcDaoSupportTest">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

then in your JdbcDaoSupportTest, you can call this.getJdbcTemplate() to get JdbcTemplate do 
any operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    String sql = "select user.id as id,user.roll_no as createdId,user.name as name,user.type as company,role.role as year "
            + "from user_role join user on  user.id=user_role.user_id "
            + "join role on role.id=user_role.role_id "
            + "where (user.status='ACTIVE' or user.status='ADMIN') AND user.username='" + userName + "'";
    UserVo userDetails = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<UserVo>(UserVo.class));
    or
    Long company = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Long.class);
    or
    List<UserVo> users = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<UserVo>(UserVo.class));
    logger.info("Retrieve user details by username");
    return userDetails;
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("error in  getting UserDetails using UserName", e);
}
```